# Whats wrong with my bst implementation?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, containers, binary-search-tree

I have some homework from school and i should implement BST for solving two of the problems.
so i started and i only need erase, insert and search functions.
but every time i run my code i get segmentation fault. can anyone help me??
this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <cstdio>
#define MP make_pair
#define pb push_back
#define X first
#define Y second

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long int ulli;


ulli n;


using namespace std;

struct BST{ // Binary Search Tree
    struct node{ // Node
        node *left; // Left Child
        node *par; // Parent node
        node *right; // Right child
        int val; // the value

        node(){
            left = par = right = NULL;
            val = 0;
        }

    };
    node *root; // Root of the tree

    BST(){
        root = NULL;
    }
    bool insert( int value ){
        node *tmp = new node;

        tmp->val = value;

        if ( root == NULL ){
            root = tmp;
            return 0;
        }

        node *cur = root;
        while ( tmp->par != cur ){
            if ( tmp->val < cur->val ){
                if ( cur->left == NULL ){
                    tmp->par = cur;
                    cur->left = tmp;
                    break;
                }
                cur = cur->left;
            }else{
                if ( cur->right == NULL ){
                    tmp->par = cur;
                    cur->right = tmp;
                    break;
                }
                cur = cur->right;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    node *search( int val ){
        node *tmp = root;
        while( tmp->val != val ){
            if ( val < tmp->val )
                tmp = tmp->left;
            else
                tmp = tmp->right;
            if ( tmp == NULL ){
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    bool erase( int val ){
        node *tmp = search( val ), *k;
        k = tmp;
        if ( tmp == root ){
            if ( tmp->left == NULL && tmp->right == NULL ){
                root = NULL;
                delete tmp;
            }
            if ( tmp->left != NULL && tmp->right == NULL ){
                root = root->left;
                delete tmp;
                return 0;
            }
            if ( tmp->left == NULL && tmp->right != NULL ){
                root = root->right;
                delete tmp;
                return 0;
            }
            tmp = tmp->right;
            while( tmp->left != NULL )
                tmp = tmp->left;
            if ( tmp->right != NULL )
                tmp->par->left = tmp->right;
            else
                tmp->par->left = NULL;
            tmp->par = NULL;
            tmp->right = k->right;
            tmp->left = k->left;
            root = tmp;
            return 0;
        }
        if ( tmp->left == NULL && tmp->right == NULL ){
            if ( tmp->par->left == tmp )
                tmp->par->left = NULL;
            else
                tmp->par->right = NULL;
            delete tmp;
        }
        if ( tmp->left != NULL && tmp->right == NULL ){
            tmp->left->par = tmp->par;
            if ( tmp->par->left == tmp )
                tmp->par->left = tmp->left;
            else
                tmp->par->right = tmp->left;
            delete tmp;
            return 0;
        }
        if ( tmp->left == NULL && tmp->right != NULL ){
            tmp->right->par = tmp->par;
            if ( tmp->par->left == tmp )
                tmp->par->left = tmp->right;
            else
                tmp->par->right = tmp->right;
            delete tmp;
            return 0;
        }
        tmp = tmp->right;
        while( tmp->left != NULL )
            tmp = tmp->left;
        if ( tmp->right != NULL )
            tmp->par->left = tmp->right;
        else
            tmp->par->left = NULL;
        tmp->par = k->par;
        if ( k->par->right == k )
            k->par->right = tmp;
        else
            k->par->left = tmp;
        tmp->right = k->right;
        tmp->left = k->left;
    }




};

BST b;

vector<int> v;

int main () {
    cin >> n;
    int k;
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        cin >> k;
        v.pb( k );
        b.insert( k );
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        b.erase( v[i] );


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have not defined n

Comment: n is defined GLOBALLLLLLLLL

Comment: why have u -2 rep me??

Comment: @shervin (I did not downvote) Possible reason is because your question is off-topic. You should post minimal example and ask a specific question instead of posting your code and ask why is it not working. For why is it not working, you should use debugging techniques likes debugger, rubber-duck etc.

Comment: @MohitJain you are right but i dont know how to use a debugger.

Comment: Exactly, you should google it and learn it (sooner is better). This will help solve your future assignments much easily and you won't see downvotes on your post. In case you find any difficulty in using a debugger, search/ask it here. But be sure to ask specific question.

Comment: @shervin if you cannot debug, you cannot develop software.  It's that simple.  Log/printf/cout/whatever some values, or use an actual debugger and single-step throut and/or set breakpoints.  If you do not learn how to do this, you will struggle to get stuff working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dereferencing a dangling pointer, I suppose because you're missing a `return 0;` statement

```
   bool erase( int val ){
        node *tmp = search( val ), *k;
        k = tmp;
        if ( tmp == root ){
            if ( tmp->left == NULL && tmp->right == NULL ){
                root = NULL;
                delete tmp; // tmp is deleted, should no longer be used afterwards
                // return 0; // Missing return 0
            }
            if ( tmp->left != NULL && tmp->right == NULL ){
                ...
            }
            if ( tmp->left == NULL && tmp->right != NULL ){
                ...
            }
            tmp = tmp->right; // tmp is dereferenced
            while( tmp->left != NULL )
                tmp = tmp->left;
```

Also: you have no error-checking in case `search(val)` returns `NULL` although this is possible:

```
node *search( int val ){
    node *tmp = root;
    while( tmp->val != val ){
        if ( val < tmp->val )
            tmp = tmp->left;
        else
            tmp = tmp->right;
        if ( tmp == NULL ){
            return NULL; <---
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: i dont understand what u mean

Comment: @shervin I suppose this should be comprehensible

Comment: Ok. i put the return 0; but im still getting seg fault

Comment: Now after the if that i check if tmp == NULL after search, program falls in infinite loop.